# Debugging java project

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, tomcat

I have a Java project which I imported to Eclipse IDE 3.6.  When I try to add this project to Tomcat 6.X it's throwing an error; "there are no such resources that can be added".

I searched over internet and find some solution that has given some steps to make a normal java project to Dynamic web project, but still it didn't work. I'm unable to add this project to tomcat. So I'm unable to debug the application, and its eating lot of my time for each small change.

Please guide me in this.

Thanks

Comment: Is the project you created a web project or is it a simple java project?

Comment: Is it an existing project that runs on a jee server or servlet container or something new that you are trying to create ? obviously hard to see the exact picture here for any body but I would sugest creating a new dynamic project and copy the code over.What frameworks is it using ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a guide on how to convert your project to a Dynamic Web Project. You cannot add a project to the managed tomcat unless this has been done.

Open your `.project` file inside the Project folder (you have to switch to eclipse's "Navigator" view instead of the "Package Explorer" view in order to see this and other eclipse-specific files).

In the `<natures>` block, insert these lines if they are not already present:

```
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</nature>
<nature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</nature>
```

Save the file, then right-click your project and click on Properties. There should be an entry labeled "Project Facets" on the left side. (The entry is not there unless you placed the `nature` entries in the `.project` file) Check "Dynamic Web Module" and "Java" on the right side (checking "Java" is required in order to check "Dynamic Web Module".

Click Apply and OK, after this your tomcat should let you add this project.

Comment: I have ever experience that problem. you can follow above instruction or simply just create a new dynamic in eclipse. just put all source in src and web app resource in WebContent, library in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib.  It is easier for me to do like that.  After that you can add server (tomcat6) and add the dynamic web project into the server.  Then just debug the server. It work for me

Comment: I added those lines and changed the project facets properties. Now I'm getting another error when I try to select the project. ""tomcat 6.0 supports only j2ee 1.2 ...

Comment: @Shekar: follow @Jef advice, create a web project from scratch and copy the sources from your Java project to the `JavaSource` folder of the dynamic web project...

Comment: @Shekar: Make sure to select version 6 of Java in the "Project Facets" dialog.